# How to define the color of a GtkButton using Gtk+3 (in C)

Tags: c, gcc, gtk3

I'm using GTK+3 (with the C language) to create a Battleship game, using an array of buttons, but I have some issues related to the color of them. I've already changed the background color of my array, and, now, I want to change the color of the buttons itself. I'm trying to use the gtk_widget_override_color() function to do that, but appears that it doesn't work in my code. 
Could you take a look and maybe suggest other functions, which can work?
The code that I'm using is down here:

```
for(i=0;i<(x[0].n*x[0].n);i++){
    gtk_widget_modify_bg(GTK_WIDGET(buttons[i]),GTK_STATE_NORMAL,&color);
    gtk_widget_override_color(GTK_WIDGET(buttons[i]),GTK_STATE_NORMAL,&color2);
}
```

Color variable is of GdkColor type, and it has been defined with gdk_color_parse(), while color2 is of the type struct GdkRGBA, and it has been defined with the following lines:

```
color2.alpha = 0.8;
color2.blue = 0.819;
color2.red = 0;
color2.green = 0.807;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using CSS for this. Something like:

```
GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider,
    "button { color: #123456; background-color: blue; }", -1, &error);
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (gdk_screen_get_default (),
    provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

This will give all your buttons the supplied foreground and background colors.