# GTK3/C/Arch - Cannot modify color; other style properties possibly work in some cases

Tags: gtk, gtk3

[crossposted from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GTK/comments/1930cxl/cannot_modify_color_of_any_widgets/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button)]

I have gtk3 installed with pacman on Arch.

I have been trying all kinds of methods to set the colors of widgets, including gtk_widget_override_background_color, gtk_widget_override_color, and gtk_widget_modify_fg.

I have tried using CSS providers - I have copy-pasted the code provided in the top answers here: [How to define the color of a GtkButton using Gtk+3 (in C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870043/how-to-define-the-color-of-a-gtkbutton-using-gtk3-in-c) and here: [Problems with GtkCssProvider and CSS styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66746986/problems-with-gtkcssprovider-and-css-styles) and tried running both on my system.

Everything compiles and runs, but none of the methods listed above have worked to change the default color of anything in the window.

The code in the second link works to create a large text box at font-size 30px, but the text is still black, not green.

What might I be missing?